# The divine fighting technique feat? Which one is considered Pathfinder legal?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, feats

I was looking up this particular feat and realized that there were 2 versions of it, one in *Weapon Master's Handbook* and the other in *Divine Anthology*.

The first one says that you only need to be the same alignment as the deity you choose to use the fighting style. The other says you need to specifically worship said deity.

Which one would be considered the generally accepted version of it?

Answer (score 3):

### Both are considered legal and accepted versions.

As written, *they are different feats that share the same name and similar mechanics*. Much like how the [Pact Wizard (Familiar Folio)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo-wizard-archetypes/pact-wizard-wizard-archetype-ff/) and [Pact Wizard (Harrow Handbook)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/wizard/archetypes/paizo-wizard-archetypes/pact-wizard-wizard-archetype/) are wizard archetypes with the same name but are different from one another.

The Divine Fighting Technique feat in the Weapon Master's Handbook requires you to have the same alignment as the Deity whose technique you're using, it lets you choose an option from those listed under Divine Fighting Technique in the Weapon Master's Handbook.

The Divine Fighting Technique feat in the Divine Anthology requires you to worship the deity whose technique you're using, it lets you choose an option from those listed under Divine Fighting Technique in the Divine Anthology.

Pathfinder Society, Paizo's organized play campaign, has introduced a house rule that allows you to qualify for options listed under one of the feats which only having the other feat. This requires you to still meet the alignment or worship prerequisite for the other feat.

[Campaign Clarifications:](http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/rpg/clarifications)

> Weapon Master's Handbook
>   Page 10—The Divine Fighting Technique feat qualifies you for divine fighting techniques in other sources, as long as you meet the prerequisites listed in that source. For example, you must worship your chosen deity as your sole patron deity to qualify for the divine fighting feats on page 28 of Pathfinder Player Companion: Divine Anthology.

Comment: I see...then my interpretation wasn't wrong. Sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Ok I did a little digging and some asking around turns out....You need to be both. You have to both worship said deity and be the same alignment as them......you would this would be a little more clear but whatever.

The clarification can be viewed here  http://paizo.com/pathfinderSociety/rpg/clarifications

This is what it says

> The Divine Fighting Technique feat qualifies you for divine fighting techniques in ***other sources***, as long as you meet the prerequisites listed in that source. For example, you must have the same alignment as your chosen deity to qualify for the divine fighting feats on page 10 of Pathfinder Player Companion: Weapon Master's Handbook.

Comment: Campaign Clarifications are Paizo's house rules for Pathfinder Society and are not intended to be blanket errata or FAQs. They DO NOT set what is and isn't legal in Pathfinder in general, unless you are playing in PFS. There are many cases where the "clarifications" change the functionality of a feat or feature even when there is no reason to believe its unclear or in error.